# Почему стоит запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, как

Пример из известного романа:

> Он мой хозяин! *Будет обращаться со мной, как ему заблагорассудится!* Вот дерьмо (Эрика Леонард Джеймс. Пятьдесят оттенков серого).

Для меня придаточное этого предложения равно по смыслу *как захочет*.
В пользу того, что запятая не нужна, говорит и тот факт, что главное предложение не выражает достаточного смысла без придаточного: главное предложение не может передать нужный смысл "ограниченно".

Так зачем тут запятая? Какое для нее основание?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147634/discussion-on-question-by-ajgy----2); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Вопрос № 220027   
  

    Здравствуйте, уважаемые сотрудники "ГРАМОТЫ"! Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в таком предложении: Этот салат можно порезать(,) как вам заблагорассудится. Спасибо заранее. 

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

    Запятая нужна.

Comment: @Серж специалист, давший ответ на вопрос, был явно некомпетентен.

Comment: Значит и Розенталь некомпетентен. Местоимение ослабляет фразеологическую связь.

Comment: @Серж Здесь говорится, что запятая нужна. Я согласен, она может быть поставлена, но вовсе не обязательно. Посмотрите, сколько примеров из НКРЯ написано без запятой с тем же самым местоимением.

Comment: @Серж Отсюда следует, что по отношению к своему имуществу правообладатель может поступать как ему заблагорассудится, если его действия не будут ограничиваться действующим законодательством. [В. Ю. Зайченко. Правовые, философские и экономические аспекты информации как вида движимого имущества (2003) // «Геоинформатика», 17.09.2003] А Пыжиков уехал служить на Дальний Восток, в родственную нам, правда, не столь отличную, часть, туда, где он сможет называть старшину как ему заблагорассудится, — так его напутствовал наш Павел Христофорович. [Александр Терехов. Мемуары срочной службы (1991)]

Comment: Он весь мир воспринимает как нечто данное ему, чтобы он пользовался им как ему заблагорассудится. [Протоиерей Димитрий Смирнов. Проповеди (1984-1989)]Наконец он вспомнил о моей благословенной теплой стране, голубоватой с рассветом и розовой на закате, и образ Марии Амилахвари встрепенулся в его сознании как исцеление от скорбей, но силы уже оставили его, и он махнул рукой, позволяя провидению поступать как ему заблагорассудится. [Булат Окуджава. Путешествие дилетантов (Из записок отставного поручика Амирана Амилахвари) (1971-1977)]

Comment: И это не полный список. Где же ваше местоимение? Недосмотр корректора, и в стольких случаях?

Comment: Но в Корпусе есть и примере с "как заблагорассудиться"  с запятой. В корпусе никто не проверяет примеры на корректность правил.

Comment: @Серж Именно поэтому там и возникают примеры с запятой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147695/discussion-between-ajgy-and-).

Comment: @Серж по-вашему, произведения публикуются без правки?

Comment: По-вашему, Окуджава был неграмотным человеком?

Comment: Нет, конечно. Либо приходится говорить о неустойчивости оформления данной фразы, либо об ошибке. Причем мы лишь опираемся на справочник Розенталя, говоря о запятой.

Comment: @Серж Не слишком ли много "ошибок" получается для элементарной фразы?

Comment: Сравнительный оборот один из сложных случаев пунктуации.